# Finding a Smooth Function With Given Proprieties

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I need to find a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$\bullet$ $f$ is smooth ($C^\infty)$

$\bullet$ $|f'(x)| < 1$

$\bullet$ $f(x) \neq x \quad \forall x \in R$

**What I've done so far:**

I was able to find a function that seems to work (at least looking at the plot). I will show the function bellow:

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
e^\frac{-2}{x-2}  & \text{for $x>2$} \\
(x-2)e^{\frac{2}{x-2}} & \text{for $x<2$}\\
0 & \text{for $x=2$}
\end{cases}$$

[Here is the Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLPDp.png)

But I have 2 problems:

1)I would like to know if there is a simpler function since I would prefer not to define things conditionally

2)I'm not sure I know how to show the function satisfies what I want in a rigorous way.

Comment: Is "$f(x) \neq x$" intended to mean "The function $x \mapsto f(x) - x$ has no zero in $\mathbb{R}$" or "there is an $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) \neq x$"?

Comment: Anyway, write $f(x) = x + g(x)$. Then $g$ must be smooth, and $-2 < g'(x) < 0$ for all $x$. A fortiori $g$ is not identically $0$, so if $f(x) \neq x$ has the second interpretation that condition is always satisfied. For the first interpretation, you need $g$ to have no zeros at all. Such $g$ aren't too hard to find using well-known functions.

Comment: The function x↦f(x)−x has no zero in R

Comment: As expected. So you need a decreasing $g$ that doesn't ever decrease too fast and that is strictly positive or strictly negative. Have you any ideas for such $g$?

Comment: Maybe if $g(x)=-tg^{-1}(x) -2$?

Comment: Yes, that's one such function. More generally, $g(x) = c - \arctan x$ for $\lvert c\rvert \geqslant \frac{\pi}{2}$. Or $g(x) = c + \frac{1}{1 + e^x}$, $c\notin (-1,0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it is possible, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)